# Função http_build_query

Tags: php, http, funções

Gostaria de saber para que serve a função `http_build_query`em php.
Li o manual, mas ficou vago para mim.

[http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-build-query.php)

É correto utilizá-lo dentro deste contexto?

```
    $cURL = curl_init('http://teste');
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $dados = array(
            'NMCLIENTE' => $nome_lead,
            'DSEMAIL' =>  $email_lead,
            'NRTELEFONE' => $telefone_lead,
            'DSINTERESSE' => $meio_captacao,
            'DSMENSAGEM' => $mensagem
            );
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($dados));

    $resultado = curl_exec($cURL);
    curl_close($cURL);
```

Comment: Tens ai os exemplos no manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nada mais é do que transformar seu *array* em um formato de [querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), pronta para ser passada para uma **URL**. Ele vai transformar a sequencia de *chave-valor* e separar por um `&`.

Ele simplifica o processo de:

1. Concatenar cada *chave-valor* com um `&` (como seria feito com [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode));
2. Codificar a **URL** (como seria feito com [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/url_encode)) em que todos os caracteres não-alfanuméricos são substituídos por um sinal de `%` seguidos por dois caracteres hexadecimais e espaços codificados com um sinal de `+`;

Sobre utilizar nesse contexto que você demonstrou, é correto mas não necessário, já que você informa que irá enviar a requisição através do método `POST` uma vez que `CURLOPT_POST` é verdadeiro. Desta forma, você pode passar em `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` tanto um *array* diretamente quanto uma string *URL-like*.

Quando você passa diretamente o *array*, o `Content-type` da requisição automaticamente será do tipo `multipart/form-data`, enquanto que se passar uma string, será do tipo `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Paulo!

Answer (score -3):

Sim eu faço dessa forma:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($dados, '', '&'));